# How do you use parameters for methods in CCMenuitem's selector

Tags: objective-c, parameters, cocos2d-iphone, parameter-passing

```
-(void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    CGPoint convertedlocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];  
    bb=[CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"Aqua-ball.png" selectedImage:@"Aqua-ball.png" target:self selector:@selector(move:)];
    menu1=[CCMenu menuWithItems:bb, nil];

    //ignore this.....

}

-(void) move:(CGPoint) touch{
    [character runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(touch.x,touch.y)]];
}
```

Im trying to make the CCmenuitem selector: @selector(move:converted location), but it doesn't seem like its able to accept parameters, Is there some of doing this in which I can pass a parameter as such.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to pass parameters in that way. There are a number of ways to do what you want to do though. This is what I would do:

First add an instance variable such as `CGPoint lastTouchLocation` to the implementation. Then use it like so:

```
-(void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    CGPoint convertedlocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    lastTouchLocation = convertedLocation;
    bb=[CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"Aqua-ball.png" selectedImage:@"Aqua-ball.png" target:self selector:@selector(buttonTapped)];

    menu1=[CCMenu menuWithItems:bb, nil];    
}

-(void) buttonTapped {
    [character runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:lastTouchLocation]];
}
```